# Delete buttons from Mini-Page Layout

Tags: apex, configuration

I would need to remove mini-page layout standard buttons because I only want to show the information.

I found this idea: [IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873000000085MM)

but I would like to know if it has been already implemented, or if there is a workaround to hide them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Relatively few of these ideas do get attention, so it would be unusual for the "Delivered" marker to be missing. And comments are being posted on the idea and you can't see the feature in your org. So it is highly likely that it has not been implemented.

I presume you are aware that if the user does not have the right to edit, then the edit button will not be shown?

If this is important enough to you for you to resort to the jQuery in the sidebar hack, then this [Show and Hide Buttons on Page Layouts](http://www.tehnrd.com/show-and-hide-buttons-on-page-layouts/) shows you the principle and you would just need to adapt/simplify it to hide the buttons in the hover detail popup that has the CSS class `lookupHoverDetail`.

Comment: Thanks Keith, Exactly, if I don't have rights, I would not see the button, but I need to show it if I open a record of this object while should be hidden from the mini-page layout. In addition, I have implemented some validations in order to not allow to edit / delete from the mini page layout. However I was looking for a solution with no code, just clicks.